# Fetching data from a URL and saving it as a XML file using batch scripting or excel

Tags: xml, excel, batch-file, jenkins

I have a Jenkins URL that displays result using Jenkins REST API:

**URL**: **http://localhost:8080/job/Build_2/lastBuild/api/xml**

**The data displayed is**:

****This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<freeStyleBuild>
<action>
<cause>
<shortDescription>Started by user Nishant Kansal</shortDescription>
<userId>admin</userId>
<userName>Nishant Kansal</userName>
</cause>
</action>
<building>false</building>
<displayName>#9</displayName>
<duration>1631</duration>
<estimatedDuration>1470</estimatedDuration>
<fullDisplayName>Build_2 #9</fullDisplayName>
<id>9</id>
<keepLog>false</keepLog>
<number>9</number>
<queueId>7</queueId>
<result>FAILURE</result>
<timestamp>1454666236907</timestamp>
<url>http://localhost:8080/job/Build_2/9/</url>
<builtOn/>
<changeSet/>
</freeStyleBuild>
```

---

**My requirement**: I want to save the data here as a XML file in my local, say "BuildOutput.xml" for further parsing. I can use either batch scripting or excel to fetch the data from the URL and save it as a XML. I tried with excel and data  is coming fine, however, in one single line. And, that is not serving my purpose as I want data to be saved in "BuildOutput.xml" as shown above.

Could anyone please help me in resolving it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like `wget -OBuildOutput.xml http://localhost:8080/job/Build_2/lastBuild/api/xml` ?

Comment: Precisely yes...Thanks a lot Joao...it has just worked the way I wanted to. I didn't know that we have wget for windows as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wget` in order to save the content in a file on disk:

```
wget -OBuildOutput.xml http://localhost:8080/job/Build_2/lastBuild/api/xml
```

`-O` is used to give a name to a file, otherwise `wget` uses the last part of the url as the filename.

Comment: One more help please. The downloaded when opened in notepad is coming as one single line. Is there any DOS command line utility that can format is a standard XML shown above? I found NP++ plugin that is doing it from NP++ UI, however, I have to do it from command line.

Comment: or any other tool that can be used from DOS prompt for the same purpose?

Comment: @NishantKansal not to my knowledge. I suggest you send another question explaining why you need it with linebreaks in order to get more visibility.

Comment: I have a batch file that reads data between 2 specific tags and assign them to 3 different variables. Because XML is single line, it is returning the value of last tag only. On the other hand, if the xml is with linebreaks, I am getting the vales of all the 3 variables from their respective tags correctly. That is why, I am trying to format the xml. Specific line from batch file: (findstr /I /L "<number> <result> <url>" BuildResult.xml)